# Liberar outras portas HTTP Amazon

Tags: c#, iis, amazon-aws

Olá,

Estou configurando um servidor na Amazon onde gostaria de ter vários sites na mesma instância.

Configurei no servidor IIS cada site em uma porta, porém o firewall da Amazon só permite que eu acesse a porta 80 de fora.

Comment: Olá. No caso do Windows, você deve procurar no ISS o "bind" de cada site. Não é necessário utilizar uma porta diferente para cada site, todos podem trabalhar na porta 80.
Agora, caso queira publicar propositalmente um site por porta, você precisará associar um "Security Group" à sua máquina e neste "SG" criado, liberar as portas que desejar, ou liberar uma "range" de portas em uma única regra, se achar melhor assim.

Answer (score 2):

A [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com) chama o firewall dela de [Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).

Você consegue chegar nesta opção pelo painel, seguindo:

> > [EC2 Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/ec2/getting-started/) >> [Network & Security](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_Network_and_Security.html) >> [Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Observe as abas INBOUND e OUTBOUND. INBOUND é onde estão as regras de entrada, isto é, as portas que ficarão abertas para acesso AO seu servidor. Outbound são as regras de saída.

Para editar as portas de entrada, você deve selecionar a aba INBOUND e acionar o botão EDIT. Acionar então o botão ADD RULE e então montar a sua regra. TYPE recebe o tipo de protocolo de entrada, PORT-RANGE é a designação do número ou números das portas e SOURCE define quem pode usar a regra (CUSTOM IP, ANYWHERE, MY IP). A diferença do MY IP para o CUSTOM IP é que ele preenche automaticamente com o seu IP público.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, para hospedar vários sites em uma mesma instância não é necessário abrir portas. Você pode deixar o padrão 80. Caso o seu servidor for ubuntu ou linux-amazon basta você criar o virtual host e apontar para a pasta do seu projeto.

exemplo:

imagine que você tem os 2 domínios

```
www.site1.com.br
www.site2.com.br
```

para linux

abra o arquivo `/etc/hosts`

com o seguinte comando

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

e digite essa linha no arquivo

```
127.0.0.1 www.site1.com.br
127.0.0.1 www.site2.com.br
```

salve e feche o arquivo

execute o comando `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
depois `ls`

você percebera que nessa pasta tem um arquivo com o nome `000-default.conf`

execute o comando `cp 00-default.conf vhost.conf`,
esse comando copiará o arquivo para outro como o nome `vhost.conf`

depois apague todos informações desse arquivo e adicione o código

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site1.com.br
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/site1
        <Directory "/var/www/site1">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site2.com.br
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/site2"
        <Directory "/var/www/site2">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

salve e feche o arquivo.

execute o comando `a2ensite vhost.conf` para habilitar o vhost

depois `service apache2 restart` para reiniciar o apache e pronto

O exemplo acima é para servidores com so ubuntu. caso for linux-amazon o processo é o mesmo com alteração nos comandos.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique o security group associado à instância, nele você pode autorizar outras portas e origens.